# PostgrSQL UNION by key

Tags: sql, postgresql, union

Can't come up with easy solution how to union tables with same columns but from second table add only rows which are present in first table.

t1:

| id | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xx | r | g |
| 2 | cc | r | g |
| 5 | d | g | e |

t2:

| id | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | jyj | u | j |
| 5 | y | jku | u |
| 12 | y | r | j |

desired t1 union t2:

| id | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xx | r | g |
| 2 | cc | r | g |
| 5 | d | g | e |
| 5 | y | jku | u |

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use an `IN` clause and say the id of table 2 must appear in table 1:

```
SELECT id, A, B, C
FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, A, B, C
FROM t2
WHERE t2.id IN (SELECT id FROM t1);
```

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y_iFFSCU)

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
SELECT id, a, b, c
from t1
union all
SELECT id, a, b, c
from t2
where exists (select *
              from t1
              where t1.id = t2.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try the following union approach with the help of window functions:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, A, B, C, 1 AS src FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, A, B, C, 2 FROM t2
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, MIN(src) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS min_src,
              MAX(src) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS max_src
    FROM cte
)

SELECT id, A, B, C
FROM cte2
WHERE src = 1 OR min_src <> max_src
ORDER BY id, src;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.A, t1.B, t1.C
FROM t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This will not create the result requested in the question because this query doesn't select anything from table 2.